# Jenkins multiple pipelines order

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with a lot of Pipelines and sometimes Jobs can queue up.
My Pipelines have multiple stages. When a stage of a Pipeline (A) ends a stage of another Pipeline (B) can start.
Is there a way to force an entire Pipeline to finish before the next can start?

[image: diagram]

few requirements here:

- can't do parallel, since the order of the stages matter and parallel doesn't care for order.
- Has to be dynamic, can't be that Pipeline B always starts after Pipeline A or something

Comment: The general plugins that can do this are [_Throttle Concurrent Builds_](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents) and [_Lockable Resources_](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources).

Comment: No way to queue on stage level, only on pipeline level `Block build if certain jobs are running`

Comment: @Grenther: when possible, provide context and details on the _goal_: sometimes the solution can be radically different and achieve much better results when seeing the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to force an entire Pipeline to finish before the next can start?

Seems a perfect fit for the [milestone](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-milestone-step/) step: **aborts** an existing run when starting a new one.